# MS Excel UDF - Time series difference

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba

I'd like some help with manipulating some data please. Given:

i) A range "oRng" of say "MaxR" rows and "MaxC" columns;
ii) and an integer i such that 1

I'd like to figure out the easiest way to obtain a new range "nRng" of "MaxR" rows and "MaxC" columns in which:

For 1 <= r <= i and 1 <= c <= MaxCol:

> nRng.Cells(c,r).Value = NA()

For i+1 <= r <=MaxR and 1 <= c <= MaxCol:

> nRng.Cells(c,r).Value = oRng.Cells(c,r).Value - oRng.Cells(c,r-i).Value

I'm not sure if the most efficient way of doing this is through some clever worksheet function I've yet to figure out or through a UDF (that I wouldn't know how to code).

Any and all help would be very appreciated. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get your result with worksheet functions. Let's say your data is in Sheet1, starting in A1 and there is a named range called "shift" to use as "i" from your question. Formula to enter in A1 of a new sheet:
`=Sheet1!A1-OFFSET(Sheet1!A1,-shift,0)`

Comment: Thanks.

Is there any way of implementing this as an array function instead of a cell-by-cell function?

Comment: Why do you think an array function would be better? If you want to fill all the cells in one go just select your range, insert formula in first cell and press CTRL+ENTER when you've finished.

Comment: The reason is that I have some vba macros that generate charts and produce summary statistics that use arrays as inputs.

Although the official reason is that I have read that array functions are faster when applied to a range with a lot of rows when compared to non-array functions computed in every row.

Comment: Sorry, still don't understand. output of an array formula is the same range as output of a standard formula. Try to search for "convert range to array"

Comment: So say I have numbers on all cells of the range A1:B10. If I fill out C1 with the formula A1+B1 and extend it to C10, every time I change something on my spreadsheet Excel will make 10 computations. However, if I array-enter B1:B10 + A1:A10 on cells C1:C10, excel will only make 1 computation whenever recalculating.... given that I have a lot of data I intend to apply the formula to, this difference will be significant.

Comment: ok, I understand now. Just change A1 to the actual range (e.g. A1:H8) and finish it by CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.

Comment: Last followup, your suggestion unfortunately returns a #REF! error when array-entered.